# How can control the date format when generating a google docs (PDF) from a google spreadsheet with script?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation, google-docs

I generate a PDF file from a sheet of Google (that is populated with Google form) using a script and a template with Google Docs.
But doing this I obtain that in google sheets date are in dd/mm/yyyy format  while in the final PDF it's like this = Sat Feb 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

The "core" of the script is (for each row of the google sheet)

```
var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(FileName);
var copyId = copyFile.getId();
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

for (;columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {
    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '%', RowData[i][columnIndex])
}

columnIndex = 0;

// Create the PDF file, rename it if required and delete the doc copy

copyDoc.saveAndClose();

var dir = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("PDF FOLDER").next();  
var newFile = dir.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'));  

if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
    newFile.setName(FileName)
    copyFile.setTrashed(true)
}
```

Where (and how) can I control the RowData[i] that are date type in order to obtain the correct format in doc/PDF file? (In the template the substitution with effective value is made with the %date name% instruction)

Thanks
Vanni

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your dates in formatted strings when you insert them in your doc in the replace loop.

The function to use is `Utilities.formatDate` and is [documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)).

It is quite straightforward to use, example :

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Note, instead of using GMT or whatever GMT+XX value, use preferably the `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` that will automatically give the right value according to your timezone (even in case of daylight savings).

EDIT :

you could try `getDisplayValue()` too , it returns the value as [a string representation of what is shown in a cell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()).