# How do I control the date format when generating a (PDF) from a google spreadsheet with script?

Tags: performance, date, google-apps-script

I am seeking clarification on the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581614/how-can-control-the-date-format-when-generating-a-google-docs-pdf-from-a-googl/35588100#35588100).  Serge insas recommends "You should convert your dates in formatted strings when you insert them in your doc in the replace loop.  The function to use is Utilities.formatDate."

I want to do what Serge recommends, but I'm having some difficulty implementing it.  The script runs great as is, but I can save a lot of time by not having to convert dates to text strings before I paste them into my spreadsheet.  It makes far more sense to code the date format I want on my PDFs (d mmmm yyyy).  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```html
//Creates the custom menu in the spreadsheet "Run Script"
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Scripts')
      .addItem('Create Certs', 'menuItem1')
//      .addItem('Change Cell Format', 'menuItem2')
//      .addItem('Reset Cell Format', 'menuItem3')
      .addToUi();
}
//Runs the menuItem 1 operation (Create Certs)
function menuItem1() {

//Defines the start row and calculates the number of rows to be processed
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = Browser.inputBox("Enter Start Row");
  var endRow = Browser.inputBox("Enter End Row");
  var numRows = (endRow - startRow) + 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 7);

 var counter =0;   
 var data = dataRange.getValues();   
 var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1baxSUxfSdzcVheR3Y2qgieWeSAqNybPfWct1913uRIc");   
 var templateCopy = templateDoc.makeCopy();
 var templateCopyId = templateCopy.getId();

//Begin Tew's code
 var dateOld;   
 var courseOld;   
 var fullNameOld;   
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var doc = DocumentApp.openById(templateCopyId);
        var body = doc.getActiveSection();
        var row = data[i];
        var date = row[0]; //like this for testing to get a different value on each pdf
        var nic = row[1];
        var course = row[2];
        var lastname = row[3];
        var firstname = row[4];
        var middle = row[5]
        var email = row[6];
        //    var docname = lastname+" "+nic+" PME Cert"; //not used in this version
        var subjectTxt = "NWC "+ course +" Online PME Course Certificate";
        var fullBody = "PME COURSE COMPLETION CERTIFICATE" + "\n\n";
        fullBody += "Your " + course + " course completion certificate is attached." + "\n\n";
        fullBody += "NOTES:" + "\n";
        fullBody += "1. NWC does NOT mail hardcopy certificates." + "\n";
        fullBody += "2. NWC does not award certificates for the SNCO JPME course." + "\n\n";
        fullBody += "Regards," + "\n\n";
        fullBody += "Professor Steve Pierce" + "\n";
        fullBody += "U.S. Naval War College "+ "\n";
        fullBody += "Online PME Program Team" + "\n\n";
        fullBody += "Learn more about NWC's Online PME Program at the link below:" + "\n";
        fullBody += "http://www.usnwc.edu/Academics/College-of-Distance-Education/PME-(1).aspx" + "\n";

        var row = data[i];
        var fullName = firstname+' '+middle+''+lastname
        var fdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "d mmmm yyyy");
        if(counter ==0){
          body.replaceText('fullName',fullName);  
          body.replaceText('course', course);
          body.replaceText('date', fdate); 
        }
        else {   
          body.replaceText(fullNameOld,fullName);
          body.replaceText(courseOld, course);
          body.replaceText(dateOld, fdate); 
        }

        dateOld = fdate; 
        courseOld = course;
        fullNameOld = fullName

        counter ++

          doc.saveAndClose()
          var attachment = doc.getAs("application/pdf")

          MailApp.sendEmail(email, subjectTxt, fullBody, {attachments: attachment});   
 } 
          DriveApp.getFileById(templateCopyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Where do you have the difficulty implementing it? Where did you try putting the formatting?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach  I added the changes I tried to make to the code by following Serge insas' instructions.  Please see line 57.  I also changed the variable "date" to "fdate" in the replacement loop to insert the correct date format into the PDF.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RobinGertenbach  Your solution worked perfectly.  I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with line 57.

`Utilities.formatDate` requires a date, a timezone, which is not present and *then* a format.
[See here for the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

The other issue is the format string itself.

`mmmm` is a very long minute format. I assume you want the long month which would be `MMMM`.

So the command to use is

```
var fdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "UTC", "d MMMM yyyy");
```

Which would return `26 February 2016` for today.
If you want a different format try taking a look at the [SimpleDateFormat Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of Java which this method borrows the formatting options from.